# How to test if a textview contains a specific link?

Tags: java, android, textview, charsequence

I have a textview with link included as an `a` tag. In string.xml I have string like this - `This is my text view with <a href="url">link</a>`

I want to programmatically check whether textview has this link and whether it is clickable. If I try using `textview.getText().toString()` it will convert html to plain text (not raw html) and remove all the links.

Is there any way I can check this? The second part is, I can manually verify that the link is clickable, but I want to programmatically verify whether the link is working. How do I do that?

Comment: `textview.getUrls()` gets you the spannable URLs in the text view - so in your example it would return an array of length 1 and `[0].getUrl()` would return "url".

Comment: For the second part you may need to define what "working" means - is it just a 200 HTTP response code?

Comment: I want to make sure it is clickable -- setmovementmethod is properly invoked on textview.

Comment: Did you try using android linkyfy. Try this. Might help you. Sorry if I mislead you by this. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/util/Linkify

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Andy

> textview.getUrls() gets you the spannable URLs in the text view - so
> in your example it would return an array of length 1 and [0].getUrl()
> would return "url".

```
((TextView) v).getUrls()[0].getURL()
```